# Reading capture groups from Regex which are also URL rewrite rules? possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

Given a URL rewrite rule like the following:

```
 <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyThings" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^cat/sub-cat/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="cat/sub-cat/detail.aspx?id={R:2}" />
      </rule>
```

In C# code I need to read out the value in the second group of the pattern (which is my ID) for my Bookmark button (don't ask) to work with pages that are dynamic like this. I'm using a certain CMS which does things at publish time, and we missed out bookmarking dynamic content.

So what I've done is load the web.config as XML and match the current URL based on what is in the `url` attribute of the `match` element. However, I can't figure out how to get at the group. Bearing in mind this needs to be generic so in another rule the group could be the third or first group.

I have a white list of rules which I do this against.

I tried using Capture Groups `(?<id>\d+)` but the web.config doesn't allow them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've got around this is using the Server Variables feature of the IIS 7 URL Rewriting module.

I defined a new allowed server variable and then captured the value that I needed that way using the IIS URL Rewrite syntax `{R:2}`. I could then acccess the value using the `HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables` collection.

Comment: +1 cool, glad you figured it out. So this approach didn't rely on named groups, just the `{R:2}` variable? And this worked regardless of the group's location (1st or 3rd group, as you had mentioned)? You should mark this as the answer.

Comment: Yep, it is much more elegant as I can change the capture group used to populate the server variable e.g. {R:1}, {R:2} on a per rewrite rule basis without changing my back end code.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using named groups seems like a reasonably good way to address the flexibility of the rules. I don't currently have access to testing rewrite rules on IIS but you might want to try using the alternate approach to name captured groups. Maybe that will get through.

Try this alternate pattern instead, which uses single quotes in place of the angle brackets:

```
(?'id'\d+)
```

Comment: I tried this but IIS doesn't allow the syntax - I get a 500 error. It worked perfectly in my unit test without IIS involved though. So I learned a new syntax :-)